# How to install Mono Develop on a remote Mac OSX machine via command line

Tags: macos, command-line, ssh, mono, monodevelop

I have access via SSH to a machine that I like to call my dev machine. What I would like to do is install Mono develop on that machine,but since I don't have a Gui interface into the machine, I am not sure how to go about this. Would appreciate any information on how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Changed this so that I can get info for Mac first.

Comment: What Linux do you have on that machine?

Comment: First I would like to get info for the Mac OS

Comment: I am still looking for help with this please?

Answer (score 3):

You cant ask for general Linux/Mac help on this. In Linux use your package manager

for ubuntu:

sudo apt-get install monodevelop

Suse/RH/Fedora/Centos

sudo yum install monodevelop

Tell us what your actual setup is and you can get a better answer

Comment: What do you mean what my actual set up is? The one machine is a Mac Machine. I am looking for info on either.

Comment: @Kobojunkie - He wants to know what linux distro you are using.  The command to do this will depend on choice you made.  This has nothing to do with OS X since you can ssh into a linux from any operating system and the process would be exactly the same.

Comment: No, There are actually 2 machines. I think I should focus on the MAC OSX machine since I have just been informed that that is the one I need to install it on. Yes, I am currently SSH-ed into the Mac OSX machine. I just need to now install mono develop on there.